# using Autolayout maintain ratio in storyboard just like group and stretch work in ms word

Tags: ios, autolayout, scale

I would like to achieve which I'll explain with an example described as follow.

In MS Word, in a canvas, we can add several objects like arrow, circle, square etc. Then we can easily group them. Once objects are properly grouped, now matter how we scale, it is scaled as a group & gives us a perfect scaling. I wish to achieve same using Autolayout in Storyboard / xib. According to me all objects scales based on their individual constraints.

Here is an example image. [image]

Here is the structure of above image.

```
 View with white color background
      View with gray color background
           View with white color bg and on top-center
           View with white color bg and in center-center
           View with white bg and bottom left
           View with white bg and bottom right
```

If the top-most parent view is scaled down, every other elements in it recursively should get scaled down.

How to achieve such functionality using Autolayout?

**Edit:**
Here - I've prepared a quick gif for the same.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem but maybe is not the best. The idea is to change the Width and Height of the root view, calculate the percentage of Width and Height variation from the initial state and apply this to all children constraint.

- In your Storyboard create a root UIView and place all UIView children inside.
- You need to set 4 constraints per child and for the root View: Width, Height, Vertical space and Horizontal space.
- Connect the root view, width constraint and height constraint to the UIViewController.

Code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *rootView;
@end

@implementation ViewController{
    CGPoint dragPoint;
    CGFloat startDragWidth;
    CGFloat startDragHeight;
    NSMutableDictionary *startDragConstraints;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(detectPan:)];
    self.rootView.gestureRecognizers = @[panRecognizer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    startDragHeight = self.heightConstraint.constant;
    startDragWidth = self.widthConstraint.constant;
    startDragConstraints = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    //I used i and j for setting an identifier on the constraint
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.rootView.subviews count]; i++)
    {
        UIView *view = self.rootView.subviews[i];
        //Looping childs Width and Height constraints
        for(int j = 0; j < [view.constraints count]; j++)
        {
            NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = view.constraints[j];
            constraint.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", i, j];
            [startDragConstraints setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:constraint.constant] forKey:constraint.identifier];
        }
    }
    //Looping childs Vertical space and Horizontal space constraints. They live in the parent view
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.rootView.constraints count]; i++)
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = self.rootView.constraints[i];
        constraint.identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
        [startDragConstraints setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:constraint.constant] forKey:constraint.identifier];
    }
}

- (void) detectPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) uiPanGestureRecognizer
{
    dragPoint = [uiPanGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.rootView];
    if(fabsf(dragPoint.x) > fabsf(dragPoint.y))
    {
        dragPoint.y = dragPoint.x;
    }
    else
    {
        dragPoint.x = dragPoint.y;
    }
    self.heightConstraint.constant = startDragHeight + dragPoint.y;
    self.widthConstraint.constant = startDragWidth + dragPoint.x;

    CGFloat heightDelta = (self.heightConstraint.constant - startDragHeight) / startDragHeight;
    CGFloat widthDelta = (self.widthConstraint.constant - startDragWidth) / startDragWidth;

    for(UIView *view in self.rootView.subviews)
    {
        for(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in view.constraints)
        {
            float previousConstant = [[startDragConstraints objectForKey:constraint.identifier] floatValue];
            if(constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeWidth) //Width constraint
            {
                constraint.constant = previousConstant + previousConstant * widthDelta;
            }
            else if(constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) //Height constraint
            {
                constraint.constant = previousConstant + previousConstant * heightDelta;
            }
        }
    }
    for(NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.rootView.constraints)
    {
        float previousConstant = [[startDragConstraints objectForKey:constraint.identifier] floatValue];
        if(constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeLeading) //Horizontal space constraint
        {
            constraint.constant = previousConstant + previousConstant * widthDelta;
        }
        else if(constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeTop) //Vertical space constraint
        {
            constraint.constant = previousConstant + previousConstant * heightDelta;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Yeah, this is the alternative to adding the "spacer" views that I mentioned. The spacer views do this work for you. So you either have code or spacer views. lol

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using the `multiplier` part of the constraint system.

Each constraint is just an equation...

```
calculatedSize = multiplier * inputSize + constant
```

The `calculatedSize` is the size of your view or the distance from the edge etc...
The `inputSize` (when used) is the size of another view when (for example) using equal widths etc...

In order to get the behaviour you are after you need the calculatedSize to always be a multiple of the inputSize and have the constant set to 0.

So, in your example animation. If the grey square is set to have a `width` equal to the `group width * 0.5` then it will always scale properly.

That is fine for the sizes. The gaps can't work like this though.

In order to get the gaps to scale properly you can't just have them as gaps. Gaps are not "objects" in the language of AutoLayout. You can't make one gap equal to another. Nor can you make a gap related to the width of another view.

What you can do though is replace the gaps with "spacer" views. These are actual UIViews that you add to your storyboard but then you make them hidden so that you can't see them at runtime.

So, going back to the grey square in the example you might have something like...

```
|[spacerView][greySquare]
```

Now set the width of the spacerView to be `superView.width * 0.17` and the width of the greySquare to be `superView.width * 0.5`.

```
// using the equation above
greySquare.width = superView.width * 0.5 + 0
spacerView.width = superView.width * 0.17 + 0
```

You can set the spacerView to hidden either in Interface Builder (this will hide it at design time) or in a runtime attribute (this will hide it at runtime).

Now when you resize the superView the spacer will grow relative to the amount you have grown the superView.

This can get quite complex though as you still need to make sure you have all the spacer views constrained properly.